"principal" is abstract, cannot be instantiated
Hola espero pode contar con la ayuda de alguien, tengo esto que al momento de ejecutar me aparece esto, principal is abstract, cannot be instantiated.
public void validar(){
    String dni=txtPass.getText();
    String user=txtUser.getText();
    if (txtUser.getText().equals("")||txtPass.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Debe ingresar datos en las cajas de texto");
        txtUser.requestFocus();
    }else{
        ev = vdao.ValidarVendedor(dni, user);
        if(ev.getUser() != null && ev.getDni() !=null){
            Principal pe = new Principal();
            pe.setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
            dispose();
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Debe ingresar usuarios validos");
            txtUser.requestFocus();
        }
        
    }
    
}


Al parecer estas tratando de crear un objeto de una clase abstracta, esto no esta permitido, lo que debes hacer es crear un objeto que herede de esta clase abstracta, o bien, declarar la clase para que no sea abstracta.
